# Show that $\sum(-1)^{k}f_{k}(x)$ converges uniformly over $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of real functions.
> Suppose for each $n$ and $x \in [0,\infty)$ we have that $0 \leq f_{n+1}(x) \leq f_n(x)$.
> Show that if $(M_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of reals with $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n = 0$ and $\forall x \in [0, \infty) \space \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N}:\space 0 \leq f_{n}(x) \leq M_n$
> then $\sum(-1)^{k}f_{k}(x)$ converges uniformly over $[0, \infty)$.

I know, by Leibniz's test, that the sequence convergence pointwisely. 
However it's left unclear to me why the existence of $(M_n)$ would ensure that the convergence is uniformly. I will be glad to have a hint\an observation which I possibly haven't considered yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}f_{k}(x)$ be the partial sum.
We go to show that $(S_{n}(x))_{n}$ is uniformly Cauchy and hence
it converges uniformly. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N$
such that $M_{n}<\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$. Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$,
$n\geq N$, $x\in[0,\infty)$ be arbitrary, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|S_{n+p}(x)-S_{n}(x)\right|\\
 & \leq & \left|(-1)^{n+1}f_{n+1}(x)\right|\\
 & \leq & M_{n+1}\\
 & < & \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $(S_{n}(x))_{n}$ is uniformly Cauchy on $[0,\infty)$.
In the above, we have used the fact that $f_{1}(x)\geq f_{2}(x)\geq\ldots\geq0$
to infer that $\left|S_{n+p}(x)-S_{n}(x)\right|\leq\left|(-1)^{n+1}f_{n+1}(x)\right|$.