Show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}x^{k-1}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$
Show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}x^{k-1}$ converges uniformly on the closed interval $[0,1]$.
It is clear that it converges pointwisely and we already know that a power series converges uniformly on each closed interval which is a subset of its radius of convergence, here $(-1,1)$. However, the closed interval $[0,1]$ is not a subset of $(-1,1)$. So it is not clear if the series of functions converges uniformly.

My apporach:
Let be $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with  $f_n(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}x^{k-1}$, then we know that it is differentiable and $f_n'(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k(k-1)}x^{k-2}$. We see that
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left|\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k(k-1)}x^{k-2}\right|\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{k-2}}{k(k-1)}\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)}.
\end{align*}
The series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$ converges, so it follows that $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. As $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly we know that the sequence $(f_n)_{\in\mathbb{N}}$ must converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ as well (it is a theorem in our lecture).
This seems, if right at all, a bit of an overkill but I was not able to come up with a shorter or more elegant argument. Maybe someone knows a better way or can give me feedback if this correct.

Careful, check your derivative.

@SeanRoberson, Oh I see, my bad, I don't know why I put it in the denominator. Do you have any other suggestions?

I think this follows directly from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779460/show-that-sum-1kf-kx-converges-uniformly-over-0-infty?rq=1

This follows immediately from the alternating series test.
To be explicit, assume $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence convergent to $0$ and let $S_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} a_k$. Then
$$S_0 \leqslant S_2 \leqslant S_4 \leqslant \ldots \leqslant S \leqslant \ldots \leqslant S_5 \leqslant S_3 \leqslant S_1,$$
where $\displaystyle S = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} a_k$. In particular, $|S_n - S| \leqslant |S_n - S_{n-1}| = a_n$.

In your case, for each $x \in [0, 1]$ separately the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} x^{n-1}$ is decreasing and converges to $0$. If
$$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} f_k(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \cdot x^{k-1}$$
and $\displaystyle S(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x)$, it follows that $|S_n(x) - S(x)| \leqslant f_n(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$, so the series converges uniformly.

For the record, here is the appropriate formulation of the alternating series test.

Assume $X$ is a set and $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of functions such that

for each $x \in X$ the number sequence $(f_n(x))$ is decreasing;
$f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} f_n(x)$ converges uniformly.


We have $$ 0\le {1\over 2k+1}x^{2k}-{1\over 2k+2}x^{2k+1}={1\over (2k+1)(2k+2)}x^{2k}+ {1\over 2k+2}(1-x)x^{2k}\\ \le {2\over (2k+1)(2k+2)}$$ because the maximal value of $(1-x)x^{2k}$ is attained at $2k/(2k+1).$ By the Weierstrass test the sequence $f_{2n+1}$ is convergent uniformly. Thus $$f_{2n+2}=f_{2n+1}-{1\over 2n+2}x^{2n+1}$$ is convergent uniformly, and the conclusion follows.
